# Toggle Show/Hide on Highcharts custom export button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, highcharts

I have custom export button. As of now it is a drop-down which shows two options show and hide. Instead of showing the menuItems show and hide, how do i toggle show/hide on the the symbol click ?

```
customButton: {

                        align: 'right',                           
                        menuItems: [
                            {
                                text: 'Show',
                                onclick: function() {
                                    for (i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
                                        chart.series[i].hide();
                                    }

                                }
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'Show',
                                onclick: function() {
                                    for (i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
                                        chart.series[i].show();
                                    }                                      
                                }
                            }
                        ],                           
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        seperator: true
                    }
```

Comment: Can you please show the HTML for this?

Answer (score 2):

replace your `customButton` with this

```
customButton: {
    align: 'right',
    onclick: function () {
        for (i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
            chart.series[i].visible ? chart.series[i].hide() : chart.series[i].show();
        }
        //or any other code
    },
    symbol: 'circle',
    seperator: true
}
```